# nRF24L01+ mezzanined over microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, rf, nrf24l01

I'm designing a hobby project to fit in a certain form factor using a mini nRF24L01+ module and an ATtiny441 microcontroller.

[image: Mini nRF24L01+ module]

To save space I'd like to mezzanine the nRF module -- i.e. solder it to a 1mm-high standoff -- with its antenna facing into the board.  Here's a snippet of what the PCB may look like, where U1 is the ATtiny and the yellow box surrounding it is the nRF's outline:

[image]

Notice how the through-hole by the ATtiny's pin 13 corresponds to the nRF's antenna perimeter.  It'd be swell to use this configuration, because it:

1. Keeps the SPI lines nice and short
2. Saves a ton of space compared to placing the nRF on the PCB (facing outwards)

I plan on configuring the nRF to a reasonably-low power output of -12dBm, running the ATtiny with the internal 8MHz clock, and sending packets (never receiving) about every 10 seconds.  The nRF operates at ~2.4GHz.  In the PCB screenshot, C1 is the 0.1uF decoupling cap for VCC, and I'll place that much closer to the IC after placing the IC more permanently.  I've done something similar using an Arduino Pro Mini, but the nRF was at the end of the board -- not directly hovering over the microcontroller.

[image: Previous work]

**Questions:** Will the nRF's communication severely mess with the ATtiny's behavior?  If it'll work, are there caveats (e.g. make sure not to run any instructions on the CPU while transmitting)?

Comment: what about putting the pin header at the other end of the attiny and having the antenna over an empty area of board?  antennas don't generally like nearby metal.

Comment: @Jasen Indeed, but then I might as well just place it right on the PCB without a mezzanine, yeah?

Comment: yeah, I guess,  perhaps even draw your own antenna strip aif fit your own nrf chip and crystal.

Comment: @Jasen I've tried that before, but the US$1 pricetag on the assembled modules is hard to beat -- especially since I can avoid soldering a mess of 0402 passives and a QFN IC.

Comment: The MCU will be fine, though something like an ADC reading could conceivably have distortion issues, as likely from the power drawn by the radio as the actual RF energy.  The bigger concern is that the antenna won't be operating as designed, but depending on your needs it may work well enough.  If you want really compact, you should probably use an nRF51822/nRF52832 module to do the job of both the MCU and the radio.